# Difference between ipa and xcarchive?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, ipa, xcarchive

What is the difference between an IPA file and an .xcarchive?

Which one do I have to create to upload an app using Xcode's Application Loader?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

*Difference between IPA and .xcarchive:*

IPA is a zipped up Payload folder which has YourApp.app bundle. .app contains all your application resources like images, plist files, compressed nibs and the executable, CodeSigning resources,etc.

xcarchive contains your app and dsym files. .DSYM is required to desymbolicate your crash logs. Right click on saved .xcarchive and select show package contents to see what it contains.

Comment: How to export xcarchive to ipa?

Answer (score 8):

### First comes `.xcarchive`, which can be used to create an `.ipa` and sent to App Store Connect.

TLDR: `.xcarchive` is intermediary step for you, and an `.ipa` can be used for uploads to the App Store.

### `.xcarchive`:

- `xc` is a hint that its for Xcode, not users. (e.g. other files for Xcode: `.xcodeproj`, `.xcworkspace`)

[image]

### `.ipa`: iOS Packaged App

After generating your `.xcarchive` and you can find it in `Windows > Organizer > Archives`, you can click `Distribute app` > `App Store Connect` > `Export` , which creates this, which you would upload to App Store Connect:

[image]

To investigate whats in the `.ipa`, you can rename the `.ipa` file into a `.zip` and extract it. You'll find the following directory structure:

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks. Why is it a two step (xcarchive then ipa) process? You can't do anything with an xcarchive other than changing into an ipa file and getting to ASC or I'm wrong and the xcarchive has its own usage without converting to an ipa? or is that you can you create distinct ipas from a single xcarchive?

Comment: Perhaps (not 100% sure) it is because you may have different ipas, based on options. See `xcodebuild -exportOptionsPlist`, described in https://encyclopediaofdaniel.com/blog/xcarchive-to-ipa/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/34272714/7365866

Comment: Just found that docs point out to: [distribution options](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devde46df08a) as things you can change. We do it using fasltane and our CI. So I don't get really exposed to it.