# Converting .xcarchive to .ipa

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode6, archive, ipa

I'm working on a Cordova (Ionic) project and I'm having trouble on creating an `.IPA` file to upload to [Testflight](https://www.testflightapp.com).

I'm on Xcode 6.1 beta, (please note, I'm pretty new to Xcode).

Following are the steps I'm following (strange thing was working all this time and suddenly stopped working)

- Build the project from Xcode
- select `Product -> Archive`

(and this is where its stopped working).

- It was asking me to export to create an `.ipa` (with select export method)

But now, its not prompting me anything, and when I check `window -> organizer`, I cannot see my build.

So, what would be the standard way of creating an `.ipa` file from a build? I might be doing something completely wrong.

I found this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934808/how-to-convert-xcarchive-to-ipa-for-client-to-submit-app-to-app-store-using-ap), but was not helpful to get it going.

Comment: Why are you using an old beta of Xcode, Xcode 6.1 is released and you should not use the beta anymore.

Comment: this has happended to me some times and got I don't really know how I fixed it. The things I tried where: do a clean, restart xcode, build and archive again. Make sure you have your project selected and not the cordovaLib project