# Exporting IPA xCode 7 Crashes immediately

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7, ipa

Working on a project for a client who has sent me provisioning profiles and certificates. Trying to export and "use local signing assets" but then xcode crashes immediately. Everything worked fine when I was running iOS 8 / xCode 6.4 / Yosemite, but after upgrading to iOS 9 / xCode 7 / El Capitan I can't export the archive anymore.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5rB5.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehPV8.png

Any ideas?

Comment: 7.0 from the App Store? Or old 7.0, new 7.1 from developer portal?

Comment: 7.0 from the App Store

Comment: Just tried using 7.1 Beta and it worked

Comment: Hmmmm... I suspect this is a red herring. If you had reinstalled 7.0 I suspect it would have worked as well. Good luck

Comment: Just tried and the same thing happens!

Comment: Same here with Xcode 8, crashing on pushing to the app store using local signing assets. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: Still happening on Xcode 8.1 - this seems to be a pretty major problem.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed by Apple it is a bug with xCode 7.

The workaround here from Mehul Thakkar helped me

[How to convert .xcarchive to .ipa for client to submit app to app store using Application Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934808/how-to-convert-xcarchive-to-ipa-for-client-to-submit-app-to-app-store-using-ap)

Comment: +1 for interesting solution. Unfortunately this approach is not working for me. I got it to iTunes connect, but build didn't pass validation. Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. I ended up using Xcode 7.1 beta version.

Comment: Unfortunately I think it will be rejected again if you build / archive with a beta version of xCode.

Comment: I've used the beta version just to export the archive. Everything else was done with GM version (Application Loader)...everything looks ok so far :)

Comment: Is there a link to a radar with the bug? I'm running into the exact same thing.