# How to create an ipa output in Xcode 11.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, xcode11

I want to create an ipa output for the Firebase App Distribution service.

I have tried to archive the project. Clicked "Distribute Content" and tried both "Built Products" and "Archive" options.

The archive option creates xcarchive file. Built Products creates an app file.

I want to get an ipa file and upload it to Firebase console.

Here is what I tried with images below.

First I create and archive and it opens the Organizer window as below.

[image]

Then I select the distribute button on the right. It shows me two options.

[image]

The first option is the "Built Products" option. I tried it as below and it asked me for a location to save files.

[image]

It creates the folder structure below, you can also see within the images, the names of the outputted files.

#### Output Folder -> Products -> Applications | Frameworks

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

#### The other option, "Archive", only outputs a single file

[image]

Please note that my question is for XCode version 11.1 on macOS Catalina

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and explain why it does not do what you require.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create .ipa file using Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499125/how-to-create-ipa-file-using-xcode)

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Hello, I added more in detail explanation and images to show the problem I'm experiencing.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Hello, the url you linked is for XCode version 10, I'm on version 11 and it shows different options for me.

Comment: @EmreKemal Now try this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934808/how-to-convert-xcarchive-to-ipa-for-client-to-submit-app-to-app-store-using-ap

Comment: @dahiya_boy The option is already on "NO" for the "skip install" setting. So, no help from that answer too.

Comment: Unable to build my app. While archiving the app, build failed with Xcode failed to show notification. Any solutions?