# Xcode crash when create IPA

Tags: xcode

i am using Xcode 14.3.1 and try to upload my app and create iPA it's crash my app using iOS 14.0 as minimum OS and I tried some solution like close source Control and clean DerivedData and restart mac but no chance,  here is the crash log

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Xcode [21751]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               14.3.1 (21815)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-21815000000000000~2 (14E300c)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       857328487
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2023-08-19 16:42:48.4850 +0300
OS Version:            macOS 13.4 (22F66)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     7.5 (20P5058)
Anonymous UUID:        AB2EA1C2-3872-E846-5975-BCAA2D269167


Time Awake Since Boot: 2100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        8  Dispatch queue: ConcurrentQueue: -[IDEDistributionSummaryStepViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
```

Answer (score 0):

From the crash log you provided, it's hard to understand the problem because the log looks quite truncated. But there are some suggestions for you.

Stack trace ends on [[IDEDistributionSummaryStepViewController viewDidLoad]](https://github.com/adamnemecek/Xcode-headers/blob/e008f7cf60be7aa8408942b2dec5a5bea5640cc4/IDEKit/IDEDistributionSummaryStepViewController.h#L15). From the name, I can assume that it's somehow related to the last step of the application distribution flow in Xcode UI, where you review all the settings and [confirm signing/uploading](https://youtu.be/Q3YhsPoSg-0?t=229) to App Store Connect. So, it's not related to Source Control or Derived Data cache. It probably tries to load some information from xcarchive or system and then crashes.

Here are possible workarounds:

0. Report the issue: send the feedback to Apple. More noise might attract Apple's attention.
1. There is some crazy workaround for similar problem via [changing system country/region](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693272).
2. You can try to generate and sign your .ipa via the terminal without Xcode. [It's not that hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934808/how-to-convert-xcarchive-to-ipa-for-client-to-submit-app-to-app-store-using-ap). Then you can upload ready .ipa via [Transporter](https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/transporter/id1450874784?l=en-GB&mt=12) app.
3. A less effective solution is to try another Xcode, more stable. Xcode was always full of bugs.