# Xamarin: Generate xcarchive from command line

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xcarchive

Is there a possibility to directly generate a *xcarchive* file from the command line? So that you can generate an AppStore build with a CI tool like Jenkins?

With [Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722633/generate-xcarchive-into-a-specific-folder-from-the-command-line) it seems you can, but I'm using Xamarin Studio on Mac. Anyway is this possible? Or can you manually create an [xcarchive file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8594173/426227) with the app, dsym and plist?

Answer (score 3):

On my build server I use the following commands to create an AppStore signed ipa file from an archive.

```
/Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool -v build "--configuration:AppStore|iPhone" -p:RssReader.iOS Apps/RssReader.sln || exit 1

# transform the archive into a .ipa package
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${WORKSPACE}/Apps/RssReader/iOS/RssReader.iOS/bin/iPhone/AppStore/RssReader.app" -o "${WORKSPACE}/Apps/RssReader/iOS/RssReader.iOS/bin/iPhone/AppStore/RssReader-${BUILD_NUMBER}-appstore.ipa"
```

Comment: It depends on your configuration if the iTunesArtwork is included.

Comment: With archive you mean the *app* file and not an xcarchive?