# Is that safe to share .xcarchive?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, xcarchive

I`m somehow amateur in Xcode and this matter is so important for me.

My Friend use his developer id to publish my app and he ask me to give him `.xcarchive` instead `*.ipa` file

As I read in stackoverflow topics `.xcarchive` have the same content of `ipa` and there is no concern about lose and steal source code.

But when I check my `xcarchive` and use show content option I see most of project files like images and sources in application folder , also some of my code are in `*.nib` files

Is that normal ? and if I extract `ipa` if I get the same result ?

Is there any security or tips in Xcode that better to active before archive project ?

Answer (score 2):

It is normal. In order to publish your app, your friend *really* needs the xcarchive, because they need to [export an IPA file](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) with the appropriate provisioning profile and signed with their code signing identity. Although it's possible to replace the provisioning profile in an IPA file and re-sign it again, it's a daunting task you don't want any of your friends to do. If you trust your friend with publishing your app, you should trust them and share the xcarchive.

When you [compare the contents of xcarchive and IPA files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591004/difference-between-ipa-and-xcarchive), you can see xcarchive contains a dSYMs folder with dSYM files used to [desymbolicate your crash logs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH21-SW3) -- the developer needs that to know in what file and at what line number the application crashed.